# PHP Timer - Function evaluates correctly within a function but not when called from page

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I apologise for the ambiguous title, I wasn't exactly sure how to word my problem.

Basically, I am building a browser game and users have 'coins' or 'gold'. I have a function in place to add gold to that user. I am trying to set up an action timer. The timer itself is working ok, I've figured out what to do in regards to counting down.

What I'm trying to do right now is add a button to the page, when that button is clicked, 10 gold is added to the users account and a timer is set for two minutes in the future (changed times for testing). If the button is clicked again whilst on cool down some text will be displayed saying how long is left until the 'action can be used again'.

Here is the function to add gold to a players account:

```
function addCoinsToUser($pdo, $user, $coins) {

    $query = $pdo->prepare('update users set user_coin = user_coin + :coin where id = :user');
    $query->bindParam(':coin', $coins);
    $query->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $query->execute();

}
```

`$pdo` is my connection, `$user` will always be a users ID, `$coins` is the amount of gold to add.

This next function is the function to set a timer:

```
function startTimer($pdo, $user) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    $timerExists = userTimerExists($pdo, $user);

    if ($timerExists == true) {

        $getTimer = $pdo->prepare('select * from timers where user = :user');
        $getTimer->bindParam(':user', $user);
        $getTimer->execute();

        $existingTimer = $getTimer->fetch();
        $timeToMeasure = $existingTimer['end_time'];

        $now = new DateTime();
        $timerEnd = new DateTime("$timeToMeasure");

        $interval = $timerEnd->diff($now);

        $timerEnded = hasTimerEnded($pdo, $user);

        echo '<br>Does the function think the timer has ended? ';
        echo $timerEnded ? 'yes' : 'no';

        if ($timerEnded == true) {

            $removeTimer = $pdo->prepare('delete from timers where user = :user');
            $removeTimer->bindParam(':user', $user);
            $removeTimer->execute();

            return '<br>timer deleted';

        } else {

            return $interval->format("<br>You cannot perform that action for another %i minutes, %s seconds");

        }


    } else {

        $time = new DateTime();
        $time->modify('+30 seconds');
        $time = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $query = $pdo->prepare('insert into timers (end_time, user) values (:time, :user)');
        $query->bindParam(':time', $time);
        $query->bindParam(':user', $user);
        $query->execute();

        return '<br>timer started';

    }

}
```

This uses the following two functions to check if a timer already exists for this user and then to determine whether or not that timer has ended. All seems to be working fine within the function above.

```
function userTimerExists($pdo, $user) {

    $query = $pdo->prepare('select count(id) from timers where user = :user');
    $query->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $query->execute();

    $count = $query->fetchColumn();

    if ($count > 0) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}

function hasTimerEnded($pdo, $user) {

    $getTimer = $pdo->prepare('select * from timers where `user` = :user');
    $getTimer->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $getTimer->execute();

    $existingTimer = $getTimer->fetch();
    $timeToMeasure = $existingTimer['end_time'];

    $now = new DateTime();
    $timerEnd = new DateTime("$timeToMeasure");

    //$interval = $timerEnd->diff($now);

    if ($now > $timerEnd) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}
```

All of the above are within my `functions.php` file. The following is the code used on page for the button. The `$user` variable is created elsewhere if the user is logged in, if not then it isn't created.

```
<?php

        if (isset($user)) { ?>

            <a href='index.php?get_coins=true'>Get Some Coins</a>
            <?php

        }

        if (isset($_GET['get_coins'])) {

            $hasTimer = userTimerExists($pdo, $user['id']);

            if ($hasTimer == true) {

                $ended = hasTimerEnded($pdo, $user['id']);
                echo '<br>Does the page think the timer has ended? ';
                echo $ended ? 'yes' : 'no';

                if ($ended == true) {

                    //addCoinsToUser($pdo, $user['id'], 10);
                    //startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);
                    echo 'You gained some coins.';

                } else {

                    echo startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);

                }

            } else {

                addCoinsToUser($pdo, $user['id'], 10);
                startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);
                echo '<br>coins coins coins';

            }

        }

        ?>
```

Currently, what happens is that: if there are no timers for that user in the database when the button is clicked, 10 gold will be added to the users account and a timer will be set for 30 seconds.

When the button is clicked during that 30 seconds, no gold will be added and a message will display saying how long left until the user can add some more gold.

The issue is when the timer has expired - when you click the button and the timer has ended, a message displays on page saying timer deleted, but no gold is added and no new timer is started. You need to click the button again to start a new timer and add some gold.

I think I have isolated the problem to this block here:

```
                if ($ended == true) {

                    //addCoinsToUser($pdo, $user['id'], 10);
                    //startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);
                    echo 'You gained some coins.';

                } else {

                    echo startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);

                }
```

The true branch of that conditional is never executing. I have tried echoing `$ended` before this and it outputs nothing. I have looked over this code again and again and can't figure out why it is getting stuck on that section - basically why is `$ended` always empty?

I have commented out what is supposed to happen if this is all working correctly - basically it is supposed to delete the timer and starts a new one with one click.

This is a really long question, I'm sorry, I know my code is probably a bit long winded.

[Click here for a working example](http://test.blackcountrydesigns.co.uk/index.php). (the button is on the index page when logged in) Username: user Password: user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to self answer this one as I've just figured out where I was going wrong. Within the `startTimer()` function I set the default time and date zone - due to daylight savings, this is one hour ahead of the time that is set by doing something like `$newTime = new DateTime();` in my global scope. Therefore, it would never evaluate to true - unless you're waiting over an hour between button clicks.

My solution was to set the default timezone within my `hasTimerEnded()` function. Like so:

```
function hasTimerEnded($pdo, $user) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    ...

}
```

This then actually lead to an issue where you could get 10 coins twice in a row before starting the timer. This was resolved by deleting the existing timer prior to starting a new one when that pesky `$ended` variable finally evaluated to true.

```
        if (isset($_GET['get_coins'])) {

            $hasTimer = userTimerExists($pdo, $user['id']);

            if ($hasTimer == true) {

                $ended = hasTimerEnded($pdo, $user['id']);

                if ($ended == true) {

                    $removeTimer = $pdo->prepare('delete from timers where user = :user');
                    $removeTimer->bindParam(':user', $user['id']);
                    $removeTimer->execute();

                    addCoinsToUser($pdo, $user['id'], 10);
                    startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);
                    echo '<br>You gained some coins.';

                } else {

                    echo startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);

                }

            } else {

                addCoinsToUser($pdo, $user['id'], 10);
                startTimer($pdo, $user['id']);
                echo '<br>coins coins coins';

            }

        }

        ?>
```